# Forcing components to be stacked from top, not vertically centered

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I am currently designing GUI for an application using Swing. If you take a look at the picture, you see a yellow-colored JPanel, which is placed inside a BorderLayout. This panel uses a GridBagLayout to place components inside it. As you can see, one row of components consists of a label, a text field and a button. At the moment, there are two rows of components, vertically centered. I would like to them to be placed from top of the panel, though. I tried setting `frame.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT)` as well as `gridBagConstraints.anchor` property, but with no results. I think my approach to this problem is wrong, and instead of struggling for hours, I turn to good people of stackoverflow.

So the question is, how to force the grid of components to be vertically not centered, but on top? Thank you for any kind of advice pointing in me in the right direction.

[image: Frame]

EDIT (code):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * 
 * @author mt
 */
public class MainView extends JFrame {

    public MainView() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(new JLabel("PokerStars"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(new JTextField(20), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(new JButton("btn"), c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(new JLabel("Full Tilt Poker"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(new JTextField(20), c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(new JButton("btn"), c);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainView();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Your description is really hard to understand. FYI: if you want `anchor` or `fill` to work, you also need to specify `weightx` and/or `weighty` to something bigger than 0 (beware that those values are not percentages, they only represent a 'weight' on how extra available space is distributed. The total of weight's does not necessarily need to add up to 1).

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Sorry for being unclear. I realised I made a couple of mistakes in the description. Nevertheless, here's a hopefully sufficient SSCCE [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bacxzdsl7z27sw5/fWb2Nfhj-H)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, one way to solve your issue is to add an additional 'invisible' component at the end of your `panel` and make it take all the extra available vertical space. Here is how you can do that:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * 
 * @author mt
 */
public class MainView extends JFrame {

    public MainView() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        panel.add(new JLabel("PokerStars"), c);

        panel.add(new JTextField(20), c);

        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(new JButton("btn"), c);
        c.gridwidth = 1;

        panel.add(new JLabel("Full Tilt Poker"), c);

        panel.add(new JTextField(20), c);

        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(new JButton("btn"), c);
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        panel.add(Box.createGlue(), c);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainView();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

While this is not my favourite option, it will solve your issues in an acceptable manner. There is a probably a more interesting way to solve this but it requires to know what kind of UI you are targetting and how you expect the various component to behave when the window is resized.

In most cases, you should try not to set `gridx`/`gridy` and use their default value (`RELATIVE`), it makes your code shorter and it is a lot easier to maintain if you have to insert one or more components.